# SSL is not green

Tags: tls

I just installed SSL to my site.
However, it doesn't show green.
My site is `https://www.treasure-domain.com`
`https://` still look without SSL (NOT GREEN)

Comment: Can you give more information like are you using self sign certificate or how did you configured SSL Certificate?

Comment: I not use self sign certificate.I'm using EssentialSSL from `ssls.com`.
First i make a .Key,and generate CSR.I give csr to ssl provider.And i have receive email of my ssl and after i install my ssl with CABUNDLE it not appear green in browser :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have unsecured content on your page, aka loaded through HTTP and not HTTPS then the bar won't show up green either.

Check all of your scripts, images etc and make sure that they're loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: but previously i'm using this SSL and show up the green,but now it nothing :(

Comment: @JaparS, I've changed the answer. Make sure that your content is all served over SSL.

Comment: Still not green :(

Comment: @JaparS, my browser still gives me the message that it is blocking "Unencrypted elements" when I visit the site

Comment: @JaparS, nice, but FYI, you should only accept answers after they have helped you to solve your problem

Comment: yes,this answer already solve my problem.In my new directory.SSL is working fine

Comment: You should try to use //: instead of http:// for the assets in your code. So it automatically uses https.

Answer (score 4):

## No EV cert

You only get the green bar if you have an EV (expensive "Extended Validation") certificate on that site.

And [SSL Labs says](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=treasure-domain.com&hideResults=on):

```
Extended Validation    No
```

And [so says High Tech Bridge](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=76bb5a9d29e57ee625d83705812252551800f707052453c259ee4540fb1b8e49):

```
The certificate is NOT an Extended Validation EV certificate.
```

So: Contact the company that sold you that cert and ask to exchange it. (The EV cert will be more expensive, so they should be happy when you offer to give them more money.)

Comment: Yeah. They cost $100 to $1000 (it's true) per year. If you haven't paid that much, your certificate is not EV.